# NSURL object not an Objective-C object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl

I am trying to make a URL with a string using the following code

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://demo.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:urlStr];
```

But the URL is always coming up nil. When I print description of the URL, I get:

> Printing description of url:(NSURL *) url = 0xbfffdb78 (not an
>   Objective-C object)

Can anyone help me and what am I missing?

Comment: Is that the actual URL in your code? No variable parameters (you use stringWithFormat after all)?

Comment: Can you post your NSLog line?

Comment: Also, it should be `[NSURL URLWithString: urlStr];` (notice capital letters).

Comment: That url is not nil. It has a memory address.

Comment: Printing description of url:
(NSURL *) url = 0xbfffdb78 <not an Objective-C object>    this is what i am getting, even if i do NSURL *url = [NSURL alloc]init];

Comment: What actually you want ,The print description is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
      NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com"];

      urlstr = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

      NSURL * url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
```

Answer (score 0):

The description of NSURL or NSMutableURL shall be printed in this way

```
  NSLog(@"%@",url.absoluteString);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question?

Comment: As a sidenote, you shouldn't use `NSLog` like this, you should always use a format string, i.e. `NSLog(@"%@", url.description)`.